# Trouble integrating conditional compilation library (Vue3, ifdef)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, conditional-compilation

I need to use conditional compilation for my project and I am trying to install this library called [ifdef-loader](https://github.com/nippur72/ifdef-loader). I know that the setup requires a webpack.config.json file which is missing in my Vue environment. Upon researching I found that vue.config.json can be used instead. I created this file in my project directory and I used this setup:

```
const opts = {
    DEBUG: true,
    version: 3,
    "ifdef-verbose": true,                 // add this for verbose output
    "ifdef-triple-slash": false,           // add this to use double slash comment instead of default triple slash
    "ifdef-fill-with-blanks": true,         // add this to remove code with blank spaces instead of "//" comments
    "ifdef-uncomment-prefix": "// #code "  // add this to uncomment code starting with "// #code "
 };
 
module.exports = { 
    configureWebpack: {
        test: /\.tsx?$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        use: [
           { loader: "ts-loader" }, 
           { loader: "ifdef-loader", options: opts } 
        ]
    },
    
 }
```

How I use the library within my code. Really simple example of using a boolean value to show/hide certain text:

```
<template>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  // #if name
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  // #endif
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
    const name = "example"

    return {
      name
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

However, nothing is happening within my app the /// conditional code is just being displayed as normal text with no functionality.

Not sure if I'm setting it up correctly but I would really appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Hi, @Nora. This could be a problem with caching. Try deleting node_modules/.cache and building again. Also, you are certainly using vue-cli, so the webpack configuration is inside the vue.config.json file.

Comment: Hi @Victor, I tried doing that but it did not help. I think my vue.config.js file setup may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this library, it allows for conditional pre-processing:

[js-conditional-compile-loader](https://github.com/hzsrc/js-conditional-compile-loader)